# Type casting error, but variables are the same types?

Tags: solidity, foundry, data-types, type-casting

Despite the two sides are same type I took conversion error.
here is my Deploy Contract:

```
contract DeployFundMe is Script  {
    function run() external returns(FundMe){
        vm.startBroadcast();
        FundMe fundMe = new FundMe(0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306);
        vm.stopBroadcast();
        return fundMe;
    }
}
```

and here is my test code :

```
    FundMe  fundme ;
      
    function setUp() external{
        DeployFundMe deployFundMe = new DeployFundMe();
        fundme = deployFundMe.run();
    }
```

I took this error:

```bash
Error (7407): Type contract FundMe is not implicitly convertible to expected type contract FundMe.
  --> test/FundMeTest.t.sol:14:18:
   |
14 |         fundme = deployFundMe.run();
```

Comment: Did you try reducing the code a minimal reproducible contract?